# bootstrap label is not working in Angular

Tags: html, css, angular, bootstrap-4

I have the following simple bootstrap label which I see it does not work in Angular but for example the button works

here is my Angular.json

```json
  "styles": [
          {
            "input": "node_modules/@progress/kendo-theme-default/dist/all.css"
          },
          "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
          "src/custom-theme.scss",
          "src/styles.css"
        ],
        "scripts": [
          "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
          "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
        ]
      },
```

Here is my label:

```html
<span class = "label label-primary">To:</span>
```

Comment: If you had the project running while you were adding bootstrap, try restarting the application

Comment: @MikeS. restarted but still the same

Comment: Make sure `node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css` is the path to the `css` file and restart the application again. If that doesn't work, consider making a reproducible example showing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

use **.badge** class instead of **.label**

```html
<span class = "badge badge-primary">To:</span>
```